# How to use different style sheet js files website and after login dashboard in Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angular 2. Learned to develop single page application for website(front end). But what I want is after login, have to use another style sheet and js files dont load website's css, js files.

For example:

Before login
abc.com or abc.com/* => load css1, js1 files only(frontend site)

After login the page should change like Admin Template
abc.com/dashboard or abc.com/* => load css2, js2 files only(backend site)

May user can access frontend site even after they logged in.

Please help me how to do this.
The sample code I tried only for single page application from tutorial, so i think no need to post here. Let me know if my question not clear.

Note: it is in Angular 2 not Angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing code in component CSS files and include that by using styleUrls. For dashboard write your CSS files inside that component. 
For JS file you can load that particular js file by HTTP request before dashboard display.

Comment: If I'm load CSS like that the style does not apply correctly. What do you mean load js file by HTTP request.

Comment: Is css files written by you or it is of any framework file?  
You can load JS like  this : this.http.get('fileurl').map().subscribe();

Comment: by me And I need separate header/footer for both frontend and backend

Comment: Thank you @mohit. I got an idea from your answer.